# Getting columnFilter plugin working with DataTables

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, datatables, datatables-1.10

I'm using 1.10.2 DataTables, and I'd like to take advantage of columnFilter plugin instead of gunking together something manually. I'm using bootstrap renderer with datatables, jQuery 1.10.2, jQuery UI 1.10.3 and bootstrap 3.1.1. This particular table doesn't use any fancy stuff (no fixed header, no fixed columns, no ColVis or ColReorder). Paging is turned on.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="~/CSS/dataTables.bootstrap.css" />
<!-- stuff -->
<table id="reportTable" class="table table-condensed table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
<!-- stuff -->
<script type='text/javascript' src='~/Scripts/jquery.dataTables.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='~/Scripts/dataTables.bootstrap.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/jquery.dataTables.columnFilter.js"></script>
```

JavaScript:

```
vm.table = $('#reportTable').DataTable({
    dom: 'rtipfl',
    autoWidth: false,
    info: true,
    lengthChange: true,
    lengthMenu: [ 10, 15, 20 ],
    displayLength: 10,
    pageLength: 10,
    ordering: true,
    orderMulti: true,
    orderClasses: true,
    order: [[ 2, "asc" ]],
    paging: true,
    pagingType: "full_numbers",
    renderer: "bootstrap",
    deferRender: true,
    processing: true,
    scrollX: false,
    scrollY: false,
    scrollCollapse: false,
    searching: true,
    columns: vm.columns,
    columnDefs: vm.columnDefs,
    data: vm.postingArray,
    initComplete: function (settings, json) {
        vm.attachTableEventHandlers();
    }
});
```

It's a table with 22 columns though.
First thing I notice is that columnFilter examples only mention the lowercase initialization of DataTables, like:

```
$('#blabla').dataTable().columnFilter();
```

If I say

```
vm.table = $('#reportTable').DataTable({
     ...
}).columnFilter();
```

I get a big fat

```
"TypeError: $(...).DataTable(...).columnFilter is not a function
 vm.table = $('#reportTable').DataTable({"
```

If I say

```
vm.table = $('#reportTable').DataTable({
     ...
});
$('#reportTable').columnFilter();

"TypeError: oTable.fnSettings is not a function
if (!oTable.fnSettings().oFeatures.bFilter)"
```

If I say

```
vm.table = $('#reportTable').DataTable({
     ...
});
$('#reportTable').dataTable().columnFilter();
```

No filters appear.

What am I doing wrong? How should I initialize it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think that you can apply the `columnFilter` with the new "D" datables api, because unlike the `.dataTable()` call which returns a jQuery object, the new `.DataTable` call returns a `table` object.

You can patch the `columnFilter` to support the new "D" api

or

Use **my** [yadcf plugin for datatables](http://yadcf-showcase.appspot.com/) for adding filters to your columns

Note that yadcf support the old and the new api's of datatable and it got 10 diff' types of filters and tons of other goodies :)

[yadcf on github](https://github.com/vedmack/yadcf)

[yadcf showcase](http://yadcf-showcase.appspot.com/)

Comment: Can you give me some directions to patch columnFilter?

Comment: I'm also considering your plugin, but all the samples I see also use the old dataTables() call. Will it work with the new DataTables()?

Comment: Got it working from the last example (multiple AJAX). I have to do: `vm.table = $('#reportTable').DataTable({...}); yadcf.init(vm.table, {...});`

Comment: Plus the GitHub Readme also shows the capital D initialization

Comment: Notice the code snippets at the bottom of each page in showcase, there is a comment regarding the API usage and where to find it... also go over the docs (in the js file) to see all yadcf features